# Consulta Existência de Tabela PSQL

Tags: java, postgresql, table, crud

Bem, pesquisei por muitos lugares até encontrar a resposta para o meu problema e achei interessante a ideia de postar aqui o que encontrei para ajudar a comunity, caso alguém precise realizar um CRUD similar, Realizando um select no ResultSet para saber se ela existe ou não. Se não existir create table, se existir rs.next(); para realizar alterações, adicionar coluna e tal. Esta foi a forma que encontrei para um sistema que precisa de atualizações constantes e as vezes inserir novas colunas em tabelas já criadas.

> trata-se de uma migração de uma classe não DAO Pattern com SGBD
>   Firebird para PostgreSQL

Espero que de alguma forma isso possa ajudar. Se existir uma maneira mais sucinta de escrever este método peço para comentarem, realizei muitos testes de várias formas para chegar aqui.

```
private static void HOTEIS_QUARTOS(){        
    try
    {            
        try (Connection conn = Class_Conexao.GetConnection();                  
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement(); 
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM pg_tables WHERE schemaname = 'public' AND tablename = 'hoteis_hospedagens')")) { 
            if(rs.next())
            {                        
                stmt.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE if not exists HOTEIS_QUARTOS( "
                                + "HOTEL_QUARTO_ID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, "
                                + "HOTEL_QUARTO_NUMERO VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, "
                                + "HOTEL_QUARTO_DESCRICAO VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL, "
                                + "HOTEL_QUARTO_CAMA_CASAL INT default '0' NOT NULL,"                     
                                + "HOTEL_QUARTO_CAMA_SOLTEIRO INT default '0' NOT NULL,"                     
                                + "HOTEL_QUARTO_VALOR_DIARIA NUMERIC default '0.00' NOT NULL,"                     
                                + "HOTEL_QUARTO_STATUS INT default '1' NOT NULL)");                    
                System.out.println("TABELA HOTEIS_QUARTOS CRIADA");                    
            }                
            if(rs.isClosed()){
                stmt.execute("ALTER TABLE HOTEIS_QUARTOS ADD COLUMN if not exists HOTEIS_QUARTO_NUMERO VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL");              
                stmt.execute("ALTER TABLE HOTEIS_QUARTOS ADD COLUMN if not exists HOTEIS_QUARTO_CAMA_CASAL INT default '0' NOT NULL");                
                stmt.execute("ALTER TABLE HOTEIS_QUARTOS ADD COLUMN if not exists HOTEIS_QUARTO_CAMA_SOLTEIRO INT default '0' NOT NULL");              
                stmt.execute("ALTER TABLE HOTEIS_QUARTOS ADD COLUMN if not exists HOTEIS_QUARTO_DIARIA NUMERIC default '0.00' NOT NULL");              
                stmt.execute("ALTER TABLE HOTEIS_QUARTOS ADD COLUMN if not exists HOTEIS_QUARTO_STATUS INT default '1' NOT NULL");
                System.out.println("ALTERAR TABELA HOTEIS quartos"); 
                System.out.println("---------------------------------");
            }                
        }
    }
```

Comment: No caso, aparentemente você tinha um problema e achou uma solução, e portanto queria partilhá-la aqui, correto? Nesse caso, o correto seria você postar o seu problema (e apenas ele) como uma pergunta e, então, respondê-la como se estivesse respondendo uma dúvida a qual você  sabe a resposta